# how i will map data in data factory source sqlwh destination blob

Tags: azure-data-factory

my source is SQLDB
SINK :BLOB

SQL table have columns
in target file which i have creating blob initially no Header right. so customer given some Predefined Names so that data from sql column sholud be mapped those fileds.

in copy activity  at mapping i need to map WITH proper data type and name which customer given

[defaut its coming but i need ti map as i stated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa7E6.png)

HoW will i resolve it can some one help me

Comment: By blob you mean which type? csv ? parquet ?

Comment: TSV  format ..tab separated

Comment: please try as updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply edit the sink header names, since its a TSV anyways

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For addressing DataType mapping,

See, [Data type mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#data-type-mapping)

> Currently such data type conversion is supported when copying between
> tabular data. Hierarchical sources/sinks are not supported, which
> means there is no system-defined data type conversion between source
> and sink interim types.

Comment: Thanks what about type casting option at maping for date .. any idea

Comment: yes, under `Type conversion settings` you can specify required DateTime format as eg: 'yyyy-MM-dd'